# Can I use PubNub to update and delete messages without "Storage&Playback" feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, crud, pubnub

I am trying to build a realtime CRUD app. I have a rails app integrated with angularJS. It uses postgresql database, and angular is connected to the backend via JSON api. I'm running PubNub commands from angular.

So far, I got the PubNub subscribe and publish working, and the published data gets saved on the postgresql backend. In other words, I got the **"create"** and **"read"** part done, and I have the **"update"** and **"delete"** to implement.

I've been searching on google and pubnub, but the only examples I got were either for a project with [PubNub+BackBone.js](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/make-backbone-real-time-with-pubnub/) or I had to discard my backend with postgresql+JSON api and use [PubNub's Storage&Playback feature](https://scalabl3.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/02/26/Message-Update-Delete.html).

Is there anyway that I can implement update/edit and delete on my current setup?

Comment: another link I found was http://www.cremalab.com/blog/21-realtime-apps-with-pubnub-and-chaplin but it is also a Backbone+PubNub example

Answer (score 2):

PubNub doesn't currently support update and delete. History keeps a full record of all publishes and they get automatically deleted based on the storage policy (keep for 1 day, 3 days, 30 days, forever).

PubNub stores all messages per channel with the Storage & Playback feature add-on. Since it stores all messages in a time series, and doesn’t expose Updating and Deleting, you need a simple pattern to implement this functionality. You can find [details of this implementation here](http://scalabl3.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/02/26/Message-Update-Delete.html).

So basically, you will need [storage and playback](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/storage-and-history?utm_source=ProgWeb&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=Chat_10_Lines), and use this [Message Updates and Deletes](http://scalabl3.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/02/26/Message-Update-Delete.html) pattern to implement update and delete. PubNub doesn't support the functions directly, but you can use these patterns to "mark" message id's as deleted.